# Azure Mobile Services Authentication, ..Identity.IsAuthenticated always false

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-mobile-services

We are developing an azure mobile services application and are having some difficulty with authentication.

The X-ZUMO-AUTH and X-ZUMO-APPLICATION HTTP headers are being sent from the client to the server correctly, yet on the server HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated remains false.

The server is a MVC/Web API ASP.NET application.

Is there some sort of configuration we could be missing to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Undoubtedly you are missing something.  I hope you mean Azure Mobile Apps (and not Azure Mobile Services).

You need to integrate the Azure Mobile Apps SDK on the server side, and turn on and configure Azure App Service Authentication & Authorization.  In addition, if it's a straight MVC app, you will need to add the OWin initializer to your Startup.cs file.

Check out Chapter 6 of http://aka.ms/zumobook

Comment: After reading your comment we've realised azure mobile services are deprecated (we're working an old project). 

We've managed to convert over to app services with help from the book you mentioned. Chapter 6 proved useful as well as chapter 2/custom authentication.

All is well now, many thanks for your answer!